# How to get number displayed on MVC calculator java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, calculator

I'm trying to get it to display a JLabel for the number on the calculator like a normal calculator does. But I'm not sure how to do this, all I can do is make it a label that doesn't change. I put the number string there but it doesn't change like it should after you click numbers. Any advice?

```
/* 
 * calc view class
 */



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class Calc extends JFrame implements ActionListener {



    private JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");
    private JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    private JButton equalsButton = new JButton("=");
    private JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
    private JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
    private JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
    private JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
    private JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
    private JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
    private JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
    private JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
    private JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
    private JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
    private String number = "";
    private JLabel numDisplay = new JLabel(number);
    private boolean addition = false;
    private boolean subtraction = false;


    private int total = 0;
    private boolean isEquals = false;   // false = haven't clicked equals button yet, true they have
    //private String numberText;

    Calc(){
        JPanel calcPanel = new JPanel();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        calcPanel.add(numDisplay);
        calcPanel.add(plusButton);
        calcPanel.add(minusButton);
        calcPanel.add(clearButton);
        calcPanel.add(equalsButton);
        calcPanel.add(zeroButton);
        calcPanel.add(oneButton);
        calcPanel.add(twoButton);
        calcPanel.add(threeButton);
        calcPanel.add(fourButton);
        calcPanel.add(fiveButton);
        calcPanel.add(sixButton);
        calcPanel.add(sevenButton);
        calcPanel.add(eightButton);
        calcPanel.add(nineButton);

        this.add(calcPanel);

        plusButton.addActionListener(this);
        minusButton.addActionListener(this);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        equalsButton.addActionListener(this);
        zeroButton.addActionListener(this);
        oneButton.addActionListener(this);
        twoButton.addActionListener(this);
        threeButton.addActionListener(this);
        fourButton.addActionListener(this);
        fiveButton.addActionListener(this);
        sixButton.addActionListener(this);
        sevenButton.addActionListener(this);
        eightButton.addActionListener(this);
        nineButton.addActionListener(this);




    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
            if (clickedButton == zeroButton || clickedButton == oneButton || clickedButton == twoButton || clickedButton == threeButton || clickedButton == fourButton || clickedButton == fiveButton || clickedButton == sixButton || clickedButton == sevenButton || clickedButton == eightButton || clickedButton == nineButton)
            {
                number = number + buttonText;
            }
            if (clickedButton == clearButton){
                number = "";
                addition = false;
                subtraction = false;
                total = 0;
            }
            if (clickedButton == plusButton){
                addition = true;
                subtraction = false;
                total = Integer.parseInt(number);

            }
            if (clickedButton == minusButton){
                addition = false;
                subtraction = true;
                total = Integer.parseInt(number);

                //number = "";
            }
            if (clickedButton == equalsButton){
                isEquals = true;
                addition = false;
                subtraction = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
    public boolean addition(){
        return addition;
    }
    public boolean subtraction(){
        return subtraction;
    }
    public int total(){
        return total;
    }
    public boolean isEquals(){
        return isEquals;
    }
    public String getNumberString(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private JLabel numDisplay = new JLabel(number);
```

All that line of code does is initialize the numDisplay variable to contain the text of the variable number. It does not mean that the label will automatically be updated every time you change the number variable. I didn't look at your code to closely but you can try:

```
number = number + buttonText;
numDisplay.setText(number);
```

Comment: Okay thanks I did that, but it is not getting cleared after I press the + or - button, so it just keeps adding to the number string. Any ideas on how I can do this without erasing the number too soon?

Comment: On detecting a + or - button click, you should first store the display in an integer variable such as int number1 = Integer.parseInt(numDisplay.getText()), clear the label (numDisplay.setText("");) and on equals click perform addition or subtraction depending on what the last operation was like se: numDisplay.setText(number1 + Integer.parseInt(numDisplay.getText()));

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is to call numDisplay.setText(number) at the end of the actionPerformed method.
You should call this method whenever you want to change the text.